# Cmake Error:STRING sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments

Tags: cmake

Cmake version:3.20.0
platform: macOS 11.1

When I tried to compiler a library with Cmake, I got the following error:

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (STRING):
  STRING sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
```

The corresponding code is shown below:

```
    STRING(REPLACE "'" "\"" HYMLS_REVISION ${rev})
```

In there, I want to replace ' with " . I don't find any error. It should be valid.
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: It seems that `${rev}` is empty. So, only 3 arguments remains.

Comment: That is true. The last command doesn't work so that rev is empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes around ${rev} variable

```
STRING(REPLACE "'" "\"" HYMLS_REVISION "${rev}")
```